# bin/sh/ 1 arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ not found with eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile with eclipse. newbie on this. My problem:

When I try to build my code it says : bin/sh/ 1 arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ not found

here is my screenshot:
[image]

Comment: add android toolchain bin to your path, there is a scipt that will built the correct one for you under ndk dir

Comment: I dont know exactly how to do that. Can you give me more clues about that?

Comment: arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ is the compiler insteaf of classic g++, you have to build u toolchain that include it by runing a script from the ndk, then add the bin directory of that toolchain to your path, the script name is 'make-standalone-toolchain.sh' search for it on google, you'll get more info on how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and i solved.
If you copy arm-liunx-guneabi-g++ from Eclipse console and paste to terminal and execute,
then you may see same message.
like this
   Ubuntu32bit:~/workspace/HelloWorldTest$ arm-linux-gnueabi​-g++
   arm-linux-gnueabi​-g++: command not found

But if you type to terminal using tab, then you may see following message.
   Ubuntu32bit:~/workspace/HelloWorldTest$ arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
   arm-linux-gnueabi-g++: fatal error: no input files
   compilation terminated.

I don't know Why this happened. It's same string "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++".
So solution is that "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++" copy from terminal then paste to
Eclipse's project, Properties. 
   Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler
               GCC C++ Linker